# Python Script to look for DNS expiration

Tags: python, sql, bash

I just wrote a Python script that will take a list of urls and find which ones are about to expire.

The program queries a database, gets the websites, sanitizes the list, then loops through the list and prints the expiration dates to the file. Any websites that expire within 30 days are printed to a text file as well as to the terminal.

The program has two main deficiencies:

1. The DNS lookup doesn't always work. Sometimes it returns correct information and sometimes it doesn't.
2. The program is not written in either object-oriented or functional style.
3. The program is written with a poor implementation of Python modules and is probably not Pythonic.

I would love to get some input on how to make this code better. Everything feels super clunky to me. For example, the sanitization process feels over-complicated, as I feel like I'm jumping through too many hoops to convert the SQL results to a string. The Popen processes feel over-complicated as well.

Would love to get some help making this better.

````py
import database
import re
import time
import datetime
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import sys
from termcolor import colored, cprint
import pymysql.cursors

###
# FUNCTIONS 
### 

# Writes expiration data to the file
def write_to_file(filename, url, days_to_expiration, expiration_date):
    f = open(filename, "a+")
    f.write(url + ' expires in ' + str(days_to_expiration) + ' days on ' + expiration_date + '\n')
    f.close()

###
# END FUNCTIONS
###

###
# MAIN 
###

###REMOVED QUERY INFORMATION### 

results = cursor.fetchall()

# Sanitize results
results_no_blanks = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] != '', results)) # Remove Blank results
results_no_protocol = list(map(lambda x: re.sub(r'^(https?:)?(\/\/)?(www.)?', '', ''.join(x)), results_no_blanks)) # Remove protocols
final_results = list(map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\/', '', ''.join(x)), results_no_protocol)) # Remove trailing slashses

# Prepare text file
a = open("danger.txt","a+")
a.write('DNS Expirations checked on: ' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
a.write('\n')
a.close()

# Get WHOIS data for each URL
for result in final_results:
    url = ''.join(result)

    # Use command line to get WHOIS data
    p1 = Popen(['whois', url], stdout=PIPE)
    p2 = Popen(["grep", "Expiration\|Expiry"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    p3 = subprocess.Popen(["awk", "{print $5}"], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    p4 = subprocess.Popen(['head', '-c', '14'], stdin=p3.stdout, stdout=PIPE)

    # Turn result into a string
    bytes_result = p4.communicate()
    result = bytes_result[0][1:-3]
    resulter = result.decode('utf-8')

    # Workaround: Sometimes whois returns a string with missing date data.
    try:
        if resulter != '':
            resulter_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(resulter, '%Y-%m-%d')
    except ValueError:
        print('Oops, something failed. Invalid String Format for URL {}, which returned {}.'.format( url, resulter))

    # Get the days until DNS expiration
    difference = resulter_date - datetime.datetime.today() 
    days_until_expiration = difference.days


    # Print results to command line and print soon-to-expire URLs to text file. 
    if days_until_expiration < 30:
        cprint('DANGER!!!', 'red', 'on_green')
        cprint('The URL {} expires in {} days on {}!'.format( url, difference.days, resulter), 'red', 'on_green')
        cprint('DANGER!!!', 'red', 'on_green')
        write_to_file('danger.txt', url, days_until_expiration, resulter)
    elif days_until_expiration > 31 and days_until_expiration < 91:
        cprint('The URL {} expires in {} days on {}!'.format( url, difference.days, resulter), 'yellow', 'on_blue')
    else:
        cprint('The URL {} expires in {} days on {}!'.format( url, difference.days, resulter), 'green')


```
````

Comment: Remember, this is code review, we can't help you debug code that isn't working correctly, we also can't help you rewrite the code to be object oriented.

Comment: The DNS lookup not always working, is that a code problem, a connection problem or a host (their side) problem?